How can an exponential number represent a complex number
I have recently watched a video explaining $e^{i\theta}$ on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0YEaeIClKY.
It uses the function $f(t) = e^{it}$ to define the position of a particle in the complex plane.
Hence its velocity would be $v(t) = i * e^{it}$, since multiplying a value by i in the complex plane meant rotating it 90 degree. The particle will always travel 90 degree to its position vector.
In the video, it first considers the starting point where $t = 0$. The position of the particle is $f(0) = 1 + 0j$, and the velocity of the particle is $v(0) = i$. Then as t increments, particle will still be travelling 90 degree to its positional vector with a constant speed of 1 unit/s. Hence, the particle will be running around in a circle on the complex plane. In conclusion, by defining its magnitude $r$ and angle $\theta$ for $re^{i\theta}$, this exponential number can represent any complex number.
I agree that the particle is always travelling 90 degree relative to its positional vector. But I don't really understand how he can just assume that the particle is travelling at a constant speed of 1 unit per second. In the explanation, he simply went from since $|v(0)| = 1$, therefore $|v(t)| = 1$ for all t. It seems to me that he has automatically established that $|e^{i \theta}|$ = 1 which I don't understand intuitively why he can do that.
I do know how to prove that $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ under the establishment that $e^{i \theta}$ can be written as a complex number. But we are in the middle of establishing this concept. So my question is: At this stage of still trying to prove that $re^{i \theta} = a + bi$, $e^{i \theta}$ is still just a bizarre symbol. How can we just assumed that $|e^{2i}| = 1$ just because $|e^{0i}| = 1$ is true in the initial starting point.

Are you familiar with the derivation of Euler's formula of $e^{i \theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$? If either you are happy with the derivation or you are willing to take it as a fact, then you can use the formulas for modulus of a complex number and the trigonometry formula of $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta) = 1$ to get what you want

Can you please say what is known about $\exp(it)$ at moment you want to prove $|\exp(it)| = 1$? Because as you mention, we obviously can't go $|v(0)| = 1 \Rightarrow |v(t)| = 1$ for arbitrary $v$.
